# Page Navigation custom permalink

Tags: permalinks

I'd like to have a different permalink structure for pagination on a Wordpress website.

For example, a page2 would get the permalink : http://example.com/page2

where as athe page i want will have the permalink : http://example.com/paginas2 or http://example.com/2

I know  a little php and css just to edit but i need you help to know where to edit this stuff .

Thanks in advance!